# Allow both Kafka Connect nodes to write to same partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Are partitions shared between Kafka Connect nodes? I mean, can 2 node write to same partition? Asking this because in our case almost every record comes to kafka with the same key and since the keys are same all the records are stored in the same partition. While we have 2 Connect nodes only one of them is connecting to target DB. Is it because only one node allowed to write a partition? If not, how can I make both nodes to write to same partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of nodes in the Connect cluster does not matter.

For source connectors, they are built over the standard Kafka producer API, so yes, they can write to the same Kafka topic partitions, based on the partitioner class. The partitioner class can be changed for source connectors.

For sink connectors, no two tasks can consume from the same topic partition. Not all sinks (databases, files, network addresses, etc) have the concept of "partitions", and that is outside the scope of the Kafka protocol if it can write to the same external service "partition" or not.